# Set file modified date on Android 11 without all files access permission

Tags: android, mediastore, android-11, storage-access-framework

Is it possible to set the file modified date on Android 11 without the all files access permission?

I tried using the createWriteRequest from the mediastore api. But that does not let you use the File API to call setLastModified. It only allows to update some data via ContentResolver.
updating the last_modified column is not permitted:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/providers/MediaProvider/+/master/src/com/android/providers/media/MediaProvider.java#6361

you will run into a warning: "Ignoring mutation of last_modified..."
Reason is commented in above inked source code:

*Column values controlled by media scanner aren't writable by
apps, since any edits here don't reflect the metadata on
disk, and they'd be overwritten during a rescan.*

..which makes sense.

Using the DocumentContract to update the last modified date does not work either
via ContentResolver and DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_LAST_MODIFIED

Comment: So it is possible on Android 12 after you call mediastore.createWriteRequest. On Android 11 this is not working though. I created a bugreport here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/207695800#comment10 ..but I doubt they will patch it on 11, when its working on 12 =(